# Reading and viewing NRRD files in python

Tags: python

I am working on a image segmentation question. I am trying to load the nrrd format images and getting the following errors. My code is shown below.

```
import cv2
import numpy
import glob
import nrrd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mylist =[] 
laendo_nrrdextns = ['*laendo.nrrd'] 
for file in [glob.glob('D:/Training Set' + '/**/'+ z, recursive=True) for z in laendo_nrrdextns]:
      a=sitk.ReadImage(file)
      mylist.append(a)
```

I tried below code also

```
mylist =[]
laendo_nrrdextns = ['*laendo.nrrd']
for file in [glob.glob('D:/Training Set' + '/**/'+ z, recursive=True) for z in laendo_nrrdextns]:
      a=sitk.Show(sitk.ReadImage(file))
      mylist.append(a)
```

But I get below error

```
RuntimeError: Exception thrown in SimpleITK ImageSeriesReader_Execute: d:\a\1\sitk-build\itk-prefix\include\itk-5.1\itkImageSeriesReader.hxx:356:
itk::ERROR: itk::ERROR: ImageSeriesReader(0000017F690AC2E0): Size mismatch! The size of D:/Training Set\1D7CUD1955YZPGK8XHJX\1D7CUD1955YZPGK8XHJX_laendo.nrrd is [640, 640, 88, 1] and does not match the required size [576, 576, 88, 1] from file D:/Training Set\06SR5RBREL16DQ6M8LWS\06SR5RBREL16DQ6M8LWS_laendo.nrrd
```

Where am I doing wrong? Kindly help.

Comment: The error means that yo do not have any images in your `read_images`. Do you have elements in your `imagenames_list`? If not, you may have misspecified the folder. You should backtrack whether `glob` created a valid list of folders and whether it created a valid list of images per folder.

Comment: Thanks.  I did check the ```images_list``` and ```read_images``` and blank list is created without any files.  I have specified the folder correctly also.  Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: I don't know the `glob`package but I would guess that the mistake lies in the path specified. Are you sure you can use wildcards (`*`) in this syntax?